# Custom geom not working without group aesthetic in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, visualization, ggproto

I am trying to create a new `geom` in `ggplot2` named `geom_pointpath()` as below.

It is a modified `geom_line()` which plots selected points along with the lines. I have added a new `aesthetic` `disp.pt` which is a logical vector which specified which of the coordinates to be plotted as points.

```
library(rlang)
library(ggplot2)
library(stats)
library(cli)
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)

keep_mid_true <- getFromNamespace("keep_mid_true", "ggplot2")
snake_class <- getFromNamespace("snake_class", "ggplot2")
check_linewidth <- getFromNamespace("check_linewidth", "ggplot2")
dapply <- getFromNamespace("dapply", "ggplot2")
unique0 <- getFromNamespace("unique0", "ggplot2")
data_frame0 <- getFromNamespace("data_frame0", "ggplot2")
fill_alpha <- getFromNamespace("fill_alpha", "ggplot2")
repair_segment_arrow <- getFromNamespace("repair_segment_arrow", "ggplot2")
snakeize <- getFromNamespace("snakeize", "ggplot2")
lower_ascii <- "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
upper_ascii <- "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
to_lower_ascii <- getFromNamespace("to_lower_ascii", "ggplot2")
to_upper_ascii  <- getFromNamespace("to_upper_ascii", "ggplot2")
translate_shape_string  <- getFromNamespace("translate_shape_string", "ggplot2")
deg2rad  <- getFromNamespace("deg2rad", "ggplot2")


geom_pathpoint <- function(mapping = NULL, data = NULL,
                           stat = "identity", position = "identity",
                           ...,
                           lineend = "butt",
                           linejoin = "round",
                           linemitre = 10,
                           arrow = NULL,
                           na.rm = FALSE,
                           show.legend = NA,
                           inherit.aes = TRUE) {
  layer(
    data = data,
    mapping = mapping,
    stat = stat,
    geom = GeomPathPoint,
    position = position,
    show.legend = show.legend,
    inherit.aes = inherit.aes,
    params = list2(
      lineend = lineend,
      linejoin = linejoin,
      linemitre = linemitre,
      arrow = arrow,
      na.rm = na.rm,
      ...
    )
  )
}


GeomPathPoint <- ggproto("GeomPathPoint", Geom,
                         required_aes = c("x", "y"),

                         default_aes = aes(colour = "black", linewidth = 0.5, linetype = 1, alpha = NA,
                                           # geom_point
                                           size = 1.5, shape = 19, fill = NA, stroke = 0.5,
                                           # Add
                                           disp.pt = T),

                         non_missing_aes = c("linewidth", "colour", "linetype",
                                             # geom_point
                                             "size", "shape",
                                             # Add
                                             "disp.pt"),

                         handle_na = function(self, data, params) {
                           # Drop missing values at the start or end of a line - can't drop in the
                           # middle since you expect those to be shown by a break in the line
                           aesthetics <- c(self$required_aes, self$non_missing_aes)
                           complete <- stats::complete.cases(data[names(data) %in% aesthetics])
                           kept <- stats::ave(complete, data$group, FUN = keep_mid_true)
                           data <- data[kept, ]

                           if (!all(kept) && !params$na.rm) {
                             cli::cli_warn(paste0(
                               "Removed {sum(!kept)} row{?s} containing missing values or values ",
                               "outside the scale range ({.fn {snake_class(self)}})."
                             ))
                           }

                           data
                         },

                         draw_panel = function(self, data, panel_params, coord, arrow = NULL,
                                               lineend = "butt", linejoin = "round", linemitre = 10,
                                               na.rm = FALSE) {

                           # browser()
                           # table(data$group, data$disp.pt)

                           data <- check_linewidth(data, snake_class(self))
                           if (!anyDuplicated(data$group)) {
                             cli::cli_inform(c(
                               "{.fn {snake_class(self)}}: Each group consists of only one observation.",
                               i = "Do you need to adjust the {.field group} aesthetic?"
                             ))
                           }

                           # must be sorted on group
                           data <- data[order(data$group), , drop = FALSE]
                           munched <- coord_munch(coord, data, panel_params)

                           # Silently drop lines with less than two points, preserving order
                           rows <- stats::ave(seq_len(nrow(munched)), munched$group, FUN = length)
                           munched <- munched[rows >= 2, ]
                           if (nrow(munched) < 2) return(zeroGrob())

                           # Work out whether we should use lines or segments
                           attr <- dapply(munched, "group", function(df) {
                             linetype <- unique0(df$linetype)
                             data_frame0(
                               solid = identical(linetype, 1) || identical(linetype, "solid"),
                               constant = nrow(unique0(df[, names(df) %in% c("alpha", "colour", "linewidth", "linetype")])) == 1,
                               .size = 1
                             )
                           })
                           solid_lines <- all(attr$solid)
                           constant <- all(attr$constant)
                           if (!solid_lines && !constant) {
                             cli::cli_abort("{.fn {snake_class(self)}} can't have varying {.field colour}, {.field linewidth}, and/or {.field alpha} along the line when {.field linetype} isn't solid.")
                           }

                           # Work out grouping variables for grobs
                           n <- nrow(munched)
                           group_diff <- munched$group[-1] != munched$group[-n]
                           start <- c(TRUE, group_diff)
                           end <-   c(group_diff, TRUE)

                           # geom_point
                           if (is.character(data$shape)) {
                             data$shape <- translate_shape_string(data$shape)
                           }

                           # geom_point
                           coords <- coord$transform(data, panel_params)

                           # Add
                           if (!(is.null(coords$disp.pt))) {
                             coords <- coords[coords$disp.pt == TRUE, ]
                           }

                           # geom_point
                           stroke_size <- coords$stroke
                           stroke_size[is.na(stroke_size)] <- 0

                           if (!constant) {

                             out <- gTree()

                             for (i in seq_along(unique0(munched$group))) {

                               munched_id <- munched[munched$group == i, ]

                               arrow <- repair_segment_arrow(arrow, munched_id$group)

                               lineg_id <- grid::segmentsGrob(
                                 munched_id$x[!end], munched_id$y[!end], munched_id$x[!start], munched_id$y[!start],
                                 default.units = "native", arrow = arrow,
                                 gp = grid::gpar(
                                   col = alpha(munched_id$colour, munched_id$alpha)[!end],
                                   fill = alpha(munched_id$colour, munched_id$alpha)[!end],
                                   lwd = munched_id$linewidth[!end] * .pt,
                                   lty = munched_id$linetype[!end],
                                   lineend = lineend,
                                   linejoin = linejoin,
                                   linemitre = linemitre
                                 )
                               )

                               coords_id <- coords[coords$group == i, ]

                               pointg_id <-
                                 # geom_point
                                 grid::pointsGrob(
                                   coords_id$x, coords_id$y,
                                   pch = coords_id$shape,
                                   gp = grid::gpar(
                                     col = alpha(coords_id$colour, coords_id$alpha),
                                     fill = fill_alpha(coords_id$fill, coords_id$alpha),
                                     # Stroke is added around the outside of the point
                                     fontsize = coords_id$size * .pt + stroke_size[coords$group == i] * .stroke / 2,
                                     lwd = coords_id$stroke * .stroke / 2
                                   )
                                 )

                               out <- addGrob(out, child = lineg_id)
                               out <- addGrob(out, child = pointg_id)

                               rm(munched_id, lineg_id, coords_id, pointg_id)

                             }
                             out
                           } else {
                             id <- match(munched$group, unique0(munched$group))

                             out <- gTree()

                             for (i in seq_along(unique0(munched$group))) {

                               munched_id <- munched[munched$group == i, ]

                               lineg_id <- grid::polylineGrob(
                                 munched_id$x, munched_id$y, #id = id,
                                 default.units = "native", arrow = arrow,
                                 gp = grid::gpar(
                                   col = alpha(munched_id$colour, munched_id$alpha)[start],
                                   fill = alpha(munched_id$colour, munched_id$alpha)[start],
                                   lwd = munched_id$linewidth[start] * .pt,
                                   lty = munched_id$linetype[start],
                                   lineend = lineend,
                                   linejoin = linejoin,
                                   linemitre = linemitre
                                 )
                               )

                               coords_id <- coords[coords$group == i, ]

                               pointg_id <-
                                 # geom_point
                                 grid::pointsGrob(
                                   coords_id$x, coords_id$y,
                                   pch = coords_id$shape,
                                   gp = grid::gpar(
                                     col = alpha(coords_id$colour, coords_id$alpha),
                                     fill = fill_alpha(coords_id$fill, coords_id$alpha),
                                     # Stroke is added around the outside of the point
                                     fontsize = coords_id$size * .pt + stroke_size[coords$group == i] * .stroke / 2,
                                     lwd = coords_id$stroke * .stroke / 2
                                   )
                                 )

                               out <- addGrob(out, child = lineg_id)
                               out <- addGrob(out, child = pointg_id)

                               rm(munched_id, lineg_id, coords_id, pointg_id)

                             }

                             out
                           }
                         },

                         draw_key = draw_key_path,

                         rename_size = TRUE
)


geom_linepoint <- function(mapping = NULL, data = NULL, stat = "identity",
                           position = "identity", na.rm = FALSE, orientation = NA,
                           show.legend = NA, inherit.aes = TRUE, ...) {


  layer(
    data = data,
    mapping = mapping,
    stat = stat,
    geom = GeomLinePoint,
    position = position,
    show.legend = show.legend,
    inherit.aes = inherit.aes,
    params = list2(
      na.rm = na.rm,
      orientation = orientation,
      ...
    )
  )
}


GeomLinePoint <- ggproto("GeomLinePoint", GeomPathPoint,
                         setup_params = function(data, params) {
                           params$flipped_aes <- has_flipped_aes(data, params, ambiguous = TRUE)
                           params
                         },

                         extra_params = c("na.rm", "orientation"),

                         setup_data = function(data, params) {

                           data$flipped_aes <- params$flipped_aes
                           data <- flip_data(data, params$flipped_aes)
                           data <- data[order(data$PANEL, data$group, data$x), ]
                           flip_data(data, params$flipped_aes)
                         }
)
```

```
# Prepare sample data

library(dplyr)

dataTest = data.frame(
  NoDays = rep(1:10,6),
  Prod = c(rep(1:10,3),rep(2*(1:10),3))+rnorm(60,3,1),
  uid = rep(1:3,each=10,times=2),
  Location = rep(letters[1:2],each=30)
)

dataTest <- dataTest %>%
  mutate(uid=paste(Location,uid,sep=""))

dataTest$show <- sample(c(T, F), replace = T, size = nrow(dataTest))

ggplot(dataTest, mapping=aes(x=NoDays, y=Prod,
                             group=uid, colour=Location)) +
  geom_line()
```

[image]

I am facing errors because the data is not being properly prepared for the `draw_panel` by `ggplot_build()` when the aesthetic `group` is not specified. If `group` is specified, then there is no error.

### Example 1

```
# No error
ggplot(dataTest, mapping=aes(x=NoDays, y=Prod,
                             group=uid, colour=Location,
                             disp.pt = show)) +
  geom_linepoint()

ggplot(dataTest, mapping=aes(x=NoDays, y=Prod,
                             group=uid, colour=Location)) +
  geom_linepoint(mapping = aes(disp.pt = show))
```

[image]

```
ggplot(dataTest, mapping=aes(x=NoDays, y=Prod,
                             colour=Location,
                             disp.pt = show)) +
  geom_linepoint()

# Called from: draw_panel(..., self = self)
# 
# Error in `geom_linepoint()`:
#   ! Problem while converting geom to grob.
# ℹ Error occurred in the 1st layer.
# Caused by error in `unit()`:
#   ! 'x' and 'units' must have length > 0
# Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
# Called from: signal_abort(cnd, .file)
```

Data in `draw_panel` with `group` aesthetic specified.

```
# table(data$group, data$disp.pt)
# 
#   FALSE TRUE
# 1     6    4
# 2     4    6
# 3     6    4
# 4     6    4
# 5     4    6
# 6     6    4
```

Data in `draw_panel` without `group` aesthetic specified.

```
# table(data$group, data$disp.pt)
# 
#    FALSE TRUE
# 1    16    0
# 2     0   14
# 3    16    0
# 4     0   14
```

### Example 2

```
# No error
ggplot(dataTest[dataTest$uid == "a1", ], 
       mapping=aes(x=NoDays, y=Prod, group=uid)) +
  geom_linepoint(mapping = aes(disp.pt = show))

# table(data$group, data$disp.pt)
# 
#   FALSE TRUE
# 1     6    4
```

[image]

```
# Error
ggplot(dataTest[dataTest$uid == "a1", ], 
       mapping=aes(x=NoDays, y=Prod)) +
  geom_linepoint(mapping = aes(disp.pt = show))


# table(data$group, data$disp.pt)
# 
#   FALSE TRUE
# 1     6    0
# 2     0    4
```

How to fix this ? This issue is not there with `geom_line()`.

Comment: Just a guess, but does adding `group = 1` to your `default_aes` (or possibly `non_missing_aes`) help?

Comment: @Limey Tried your suggestion. There is no effect. The issue persists.